# XML Schema: Cannot resolve the name type definition

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I am defining the schema, but on validating it in eclipse, it gives the following error.

> [Error] :1125:55: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'YesNoDoesNotApplyType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

My schema looks like the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="9.00" id="R2014.1">
<xs:include schemaLocation="ATA_CommonTypes.xsd"/>

<xs:element name="ABT" type="YesNoDoesNotApplyType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Aborted Approach Indicator</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and `ATA_CommonTypes.xsd` looks like following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.00" id="R2007.1">

<xs:simpleType name="YesNoDoesNotApplyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="D">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Does Not Apply</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="N">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>No</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="Y">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Yes</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

My eclipse function as follows: and it give the error from the below line
XSModel model = schemaLoader.load( input );

```
private SchemaAlertFormatterUtil(String schemaUriBase) {
  try {
     InputStream schemaInputStream =
           this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( schemaUriBase + CSDD_MM_XSD );
     DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
     XSImplementation xsImplementation =
           ( XSImplementation ) registry.getDOMImplementation( "XS-Loader" );

     XSLoader schemaLoader = xsImplementation.createXSLoader( null );
     LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
     input.setByteStream( schemaInputStream );
     XSModel model = schemaLoader.load( input );

     annotationBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
     // Read and add all element declarations
     XSNamedMap elements = model.getComponents( XSConstants.ELEMENT_DECLARATION );
     for ( int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++ ) {
        XSElementDeclaration item = ( XSElementDeclaration ) elements.item( i );
        addItemToMapper( item.getName(), item.getAnnotation() );
     }

     // Read and add all attribute declarations
     XSNamedMap attributes = model.getComponents( XSConstants.ATTRIBUTE_DECLARATION );
     for ( int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++ ) {
        XSAttributeDeclaration item = ( XSAttributeDeclaration ) attributes.item( i );
        addItemToMapper( item.getName(), item.getAnnotation() );
     }
  } catch ( Exception exception ) {
     LOGGER.error( "Error occured when loading CSDD_MM.xsd", exception );
  }}
```

Comment: Issue got solved after defining XML path as a absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation lies in something you haven't shown us, and the most important thing you haven't shown us is the target namespace of the schema document. If the schema document has a target namespace, then the type will be in that namespace, and the reference to the type has to be qualified with an appropriate prefix.

Comment: There are no name spaces
My schema header like as follows

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="9.00" id="R2014.1">
 <xs:include schemaLocation="ATA_CommonTypes.xsd"/>
 <xs:annotation>

All the 2 schema is in the same location.

And I have imported the schema as above, No errors shown in the XML spy, but when it executed from the eclipse it gives the error.